# Magic number in boost::hash_combine

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, hash, magic-numbers

The `boost::hash_combine` template function takes a reference to a hash (called `seed`) and an object `v`. According to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine), it combines `seed` with the hash of `v` by

```cpp
seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
```

I can see that this is deterministic. I see why a XOR is used.

I bet the addition helps in mapping similar values widely apart so probing hash tables won't break down, but can someone explain what the magic constant is?

Comment: Given that on many computers an integer rotate cost about the same as a shift would there be any benefit in converting the expression to:

<code>
    seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + rotl(seed, 6) + rotr(seed, 2);
</code>

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The magic number is supposed to be 32 random bits, where each is equally likely to be 0 or 1, and with no simple correlation between the bits. A common way to find a string of such bits is to use the binary expansion of an irrational number; in this case, that number is the reciprocal of the golden ratio:

```
phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
2^32 / phi = 0x9e3779b9
```

So including this number "randomly" changes each bit of the seed; as you say, this means that consecutive values will be far apart. Including the shifted versions of the old seed makes sure that, even if `hash_value()` has a fairly small range of values, differences will soon be spread across all the bits.

Comment: Nice, I had read they had noticed it worked pretty well but didn't knew it came from the golden ratio :)

Comment: Cool! I like it when number theory suddenly gets useful :)

Comment: @larsmans I love your use of 'suddenly' - it's very appropriate! Number theory is like "yeah, that's nice... but I've got real work to do, sorry" in 99% of all cases. And then, as you say, 'suddenly', number theory is super super useful. It's not like a hammer where it's *rather* useful for a large number of things. Instead, it's like a scalpel being *extremely* useful for a small number of things.

Comment: So the magic number should be different depending on `sizeof(size_t)`?

Comment: @dalle, that would make sense. This one liner: `python -c "import math; print hex(int(2**64 / (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2))"` produced `0x278dde6e5fd29e00` for me. I expect that would work fairly well for when size_t is 64-bits.

Comment: @SamKellett Would work even better if you used the correct number of parentheses and got `0x9e3779b97f4a7800`

Comment: Because Python's floating point number doesn't have enough precision, the 64-bit golden ratios above are not correct. The actual result should be `0x9e3779b97f4a7c15`.

Comment: Speaking of which, this assumes that the golden ratio is what is called a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) - which it probably is.

Comment: @kennytm Don't you mean [`0x9e3779b97f4a7c16`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c977420af344e736)? I mean, it's only 1 off.

Comment: @bit2shift That depends on whether you want to round up or round down.

Comment: @kennytm that value is rounded down by casting. Which formula did you actually use? Oh wait, let me guess, you divided `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` by `phi` and not `2^64`.

Comment: @bit2shift rounding down is definitely 0x...c15. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(2%5E64+%2F+golden+ratio)+in+base+16

Comment: @kennytm WolframAlpha has [loss of precision](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(2%5E64+%2F+%7B(sqrt(5)+*+0.5+%2B+0.5),+((1+%2B+sqrt(5))+%2F+2),+golden+ratio%7D)) between operations.

Comment: @kennytm you have no way of specifying the desired precision in there. Try `long double` instead.

Comment: @bit2shift You are introducing loss of precision because of the "0.5" (which defaults to 7 digits). Use "1/2" for exact arithmetic, or use "0.500000000000000000" if you want more precision. `long double` only has 64 bits of precision, it is not quite enough for the computation here.

Comment: Ruby console:
```
> require 'bigdecimal'
=> true
> d64=BigDecimal.new(1<<64)
=> 0.18446744073709551616e20
> phi=(1+BigDecimal.new(5).sqrt(64))/2
=> 0.16180339887498948482045868343656381177203091798057628621354486227052604625714285715e1
> (d64/phi).to_i.to_s(16)
=> "9e3779b97f4a7c15"
> (d64/phi * (1<<16)).to_i.to_s(16)
=> "9e3779b97f4a7c15f39c"
```
Therefore "round to nearest" is certainly 0x9e3779b97f4a7c16
But for use as multiplicator 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15 is more preffered since it has lowest bit set.

Comment: Funnily 1 / phi = phi - 1. No division is needed. And Wikipedia has golden ratio as Hexadecimal 1.9E3779B97F4A7C15. So it would seem 5 is correct and not 6?

Answer (score 29):

Take a look at the [DDJ article by Bob Jenkins from 1997](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html). The magic constant ("golden ratio") is explained as follows:

> The golden ratio really is an arbitrary value. Its purpose is to avoid mapping all zeros to all zeros.

Answer (score 1):

using python to get this mgic number:

```py
from math import sqrt
phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
hex(int(2**32/phi))
```