# How to write qHash for a QSet<SomeClass*> container?

Tags: c++, qt, hash, containers

I need to implement a set of sets in my application.
Using QSet with a custom class requires providing a `qHash()` function and an `operator==`.

The code is as follows:

```
    class Custom{
        int x;
        int y;
        //some other irrelevant here
    }
    inline uint qHash(Custom* c){
        return (qHash(c->x) ^ qHash(c->y));
    }
    bool operator==(Custom &c1, Custom &c2){
        return ((c1.x==c2.x) && (c1.y == c2.y));
    }

    //now I can use: QSet<Custom*>
```

How can I implement `qHash(QSet<Custom*>)`, to be able to use `QSet< QSet<SomeClass*> >`?

Edit:

Additional question:
In my application the "set of sets" can contain up to 15000 sets. Each subset up to 25 Custom class pointers. How to guarantee that `qHash(QSet<Custom*>)` will be unique enough?

Comment: Are you sure about the `QSet<Custom*>`? Shouldn't that be `QSet<Custom,...>`? Your `operator==` for `Custom` will never be called by `QHash`, since it uses the built-in equality operator for pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to hash containers is to combine the hashes of all elements. Boost provides [hash_combine and hash_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) for this purpose. This should give you an idea how to implement this for the results of your `qHash`.

So, given your `qHash` for `Custom`:

```
uint qHash(const QSet<Custom*>& c) {
  uint seed = 0;

  for(auto x : c) {
    seed ^= qHash(x) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
  }

  return seed;
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but can I be sure that the hash will be unique? Of course I can test it in my code, but maybe there is some theory behind that?

Comment: @piotr You might want to add this to your question. Now you only ask for an implementation. Here are some hints as to what this does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-numbers-in-boosthash-combine

Comment: @Piotr: you can _never_ be sure the hash is unique. In fact, it is guaranteed _not_ to be unique simply because the hash value doesn't have enough bits to represent all possible sets (which is infinite, at  least theoretically). That's why you also need an `operator==` - to detect collisions and handle them correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot implement `qHash` with `boost::hash_range`/[`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) (which is what pmr's answer does, effectively), because `QSet` is the Qt equivalent of `std::unordered_set`, and, as the STL name suggests, these containers are *unordered*, whereas the [Boost Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) states that `hash_combine` is order-dependent, ie. it will hash permutations to *different* hash values.

This is a problem because if you naively hash-combine the elements in stored order
you cannot guarantee that two sets that compare equal are, indeed, equal, which is one of the requirements of a hash function:

```
For all x, y:   x == y => qHash(x) == qHash(y)
```

So, if your hash-combining function needs to produce the same output for any permutation of the input values, it needs to be *commutative*. Fortunately, both (unsigned) addition and the xor operation just fit the bill:

```
template <typename T>
inline uint qHash(const QSet<T> &set, uint seed=0) {
    return std::accumulate(set.begin(), set.end(), seed,
                           [](uint seed, const T&value) {
                               return seed + qHash(value); // or ^
                           });
}
```