# Using a QSet as a key in Qt map container

Tags: c++, qt

I need a map where the keys will be unique, and each key will be a set or a custom POD struct which contains 3 data items. The values are simply pointers to object instances.

From reading the [docs for Qt's QMap vs QHash](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#details), it appears as though if I use [QSet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qset.html) as the key in my map, then I should use QHash since QSet provides `operator==()` but not `operator<()`. Is this a fair assumption?  However, the docs also say that QHash requires a "global qHash function called qHash()", but it is not clear to me how this is provided, or if it is an implicit part of QSet?

If alternatively I use a simple struct as my key, I run into the same issue of dealing with `qHash()`, though a simple POD struct should implicitly have an acceptable overload of `operator==()` that simply compares all the data, correct?

I'd appreciate some advice on the best approach here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126470/how-to-write-qhash-for-a-qsetsomeclass-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise using `QHash` unless you need to sort your keys (which I assume you don't).

The `operator==` function is already provided by `QSet`, assuming the class which is managed by the set has that operator defined as well (all of the basic data types and `QString` etc have that).

> Two sets are considered equal if they contain the same elements.
>
> This function requires the value type to implement operator==().

You still need to provide the `qHash()` function which is usally defined like this:

```
inline uint qHash( QSet<whatever> set )
{
    return /* calculate a hash based on all the elements. */
}
```

This definition can really be placed anywhere, as long as the code which defines the `QHash` includes the file which contains the definition. If you have an own class for what is referenced as `whatever` in this example, you would put that definition e.g. behind your class definition.

Note that the `qHash` function only needs to ensure that the result of the equation `obj1 == obj2` is always equal to the result of `qHash(obj1) == qHash(obj2)`.

This means you don't necessarily have to produce unique hashes, but there is the following note in the documentation:

> However, to obtain good performance, the qHash() function should attempt to return different hash values for different keys to the largest extent possible.

---

### Examples:

I wrote a small test application for a set which stores strings:

```
#include <QtCore/QSet>
#include <QtCore/QHash>
#include <QtCore/QList>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>    

typedef QSet<QString> QStringSet;
typedef QHash< QStringSet, QObject* > QStringSetToObjectHash;

inline uint qHash( const QStringSet mySet )
{
    // convert the set to a list so we can sort and iterate over it
    QList<QString> mySetAsList = mySet.toList();
    qSort( mySetAsList );

    // take the hash of the first item
    uint result = qHash( mySetAsList.first() );

    // for each remaining element in the list
    for( int index = 1; index < mySetAsList.count(); index++ )
    {
        // XOR the current result with the hash of the next item
        result ^= qHash( mySetAsList.at( index ) );
    }

    return result;
}
   
void insertIntoHash( QStringSetToObjectHash& hash, const QStringSet& key, QObject* const value )
{
    qDebug() << "---------------------------------";
    qDebug() << "Element hash value:" << qHash( key );

    foreach( QStringSet existingKey, hash.keys() )
    {
        if( existingKey == key )
        {
            qDebug() << "Similar element found using == operator. QHash will not store that item twice";
        }
    }

    hash.insert( key, value );
    qDebug() << "QHash count:" << hash.count();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QStringSetToObjectHash testHash;

    QObject dummy;

    QStringSet testSet;
    testSet.insert( "1" );
    testSet.insert( "12" );

    insertIntoHash( testHash, testSet, &dummy );

    QStringSet testSet2( testSet );

    insertIntoHash( testHash, testSet2, &dummy );

    QStringSet testSet3;
    testSet3.insert( "12" );
    testSet3.insert( "1" );

    insertIntoHash( testHash, testSet3, &dummy );

    QStringSet testSet4;
    testSet4.insert( "1" );
    testSet4.insert( "2" );
    testSet4.insert( "3" );

    insertIntoHash( testHash, testSet4, &dummy );
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
--------------------------------- 
Element hash value: 883
QHash count: 1 
---------------------------------
Element hash value: 883  Similar element found using == operator. QHash will not store that item twice
QHash count: 1 
---------------------------------
Element hash value: 883  Similar element found using == operator. QHash will not store that item twice
QHash count: 1 
--------------------------------- 
Element hash value: 48
QHash count: 2
```