# How can I use an unordered_set with a custom struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, set, unordered-set

I want to use an `unordered_set` with a custom `struct`. In my case, the custom `struct` represents a 2D point in an euclidean plane. I know that one should define a hash function and comparator operator and I have done so as you can see in my code below:

```
struct Point {
    int X;
    int Y;

    Point() : X(0), Y(0) {};
    Point(const int& x, const int& y) : X(x), Y(y) {};
    Point(const IPoint& other){
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
    };

    Point& operator=(const Point& other) {
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
        return *this;
    };

    bool operator==(const Point& other) {
        if (X == other.X && Y == other.Y)
            return true;
        return false;
    };

    bool operator<(const Point& other) {
        if (X < other.X )
            return true;
        else if (X == other.X && Y == other.Y)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    size_t operator()(const Point& pointToHash) const {
        size_t hash = pointToHash.X + 10 * pointToHash.Y;
        return hash;
    };
};
```

However, I'm getting the error below, if I define the set as follows:

```
unordered_set<Point> mySet;
```

> Error C2280   'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)':
>   attempting to reference a deleted function

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second template parameter to std::unordered_set is the type to use for hashing. and will default to `std::hash<Point>` in your case, which doesn't exist. So you can use  `std::unordered_set<Point,Point>` if the hasher is the same type.

Alternatively if you do not want to specify the hasher, define a specialization of `std::hash` for `Point` and either get rid of the member function and implement the hashing in the body of your specialization's `operator()`, or call the member function from the std::hash specialization.

```
#include <unordered_set>

struct Point {
    int X;
    int Y;

    Point() : X(0), Y(0) {};
    Point(const int& x, const int& y) : X(x), Y(y) {};
    Point(const Point& other){
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
    };

    Point& operator=(const Point& other) {
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
        return *this;
    };

    bool operator==(const Point& other) const {
        if (X == other.X && Y == other.Y)
            return true;
        return false;
    };

    bool operator<(const Point& other) {
        if (X < other.X )
            return true;
        else if (X == other.X && Y == other.Y)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    // this could be moved in to std::hash<Point>::operator()
    size_t operator()(const Point& pointToHash) const noexcept {
        size_t hash = pointToHash.X + 10 * pointToHash.Y;
        return hash;
    };

};

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<Point>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const Point& p) const noexcept
        {
            return p(p);
        }
    };
}


int main()
{
    // no need to specify the hasher if std::hash<Point> exists
    std::unordered_set<Point> p;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/OOdbFx)

Comment: Thanks @rmawatson!
I've decided to go with the first option - specifying the hash function.
Pretty new to all of the new unordered associative structures and I sure have a lot to learn on this.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to expand on [rmawatson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50888147/2675154) by providing some more tips:

1. For your `struct`, you neither need to define `operator=` nor `Point(const Point& other)`, because you (re-)implemented the default behavior.
2. You can streamline `operator==` by removing the `if` clause as follows:

   ```
   bool operator==(const Point& other) { return X == other.X && Y == other.Y; };
   ```
3. There is a mistake in your `operator<`: In the `else if` clause, you return `true` if both points are equal. This violates the requirement for a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Therefore, I recommend to use the following code instead:

   ```
   bool operator<(const Point& other) { return X < other.X || (X == other.X && Y < other.Y); };
   ```

Moreover, since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can use [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining the hash and comparison functions. This way, you don't need to specify any operators for your `struct`, if you don't need them otherwise. Putting everything together, your code could be written as follows:

```
struct Point {
    int X, Y;

    Point() : X(0), Y(0) {};
    Point(const int x, const int y) : X(x), Y(y) {};
};

int main() {
    auto hash = [](const Point& p) { return p.X + 10 * p.Y; };
    auto equal = [](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) { return p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y; };
    std::unordered_set<Point, decltype(hash), decltype(equal)> mySet(8, hash, equal);

    return 0;
}
```

However, as also explained in [CJ13's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787996/2675154), your hash function might not be the best one. Another way to [handcraft a hash function](https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers) is the following:

```
auto hash = [](const Point& p) { return std::hash<int>()(p.X) * 31 + std::hash<int>()(p.Y); };
```

The idea for a more general solution to hashing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729747/2675154).

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZA6IKr)

Answer (score 7):

While the above solution gets you compiling code, avoid that hash function for points. There's a one dimensional subspace parameterized by `b` for which all points on the line `y = -x/10 + b` will have the same hash value. You'd be better off with a 64 bit hash where the top 32 bits are the x coord and the low 32 bits are the y coord (for example). That'd look like

```
uint64_t hash(Point const & p) const noexcept
{
    return ((uint64_t)p.X)<<32 | (uint64_t)p.Y;
}
```