# How to properly hash the custom struct?

Tags: c++, hash, probability

In the C++ language there is the default hash-function template `std::hash<T>` for the most simple types, like `std::string`, `int`, etc. I suppose, that these functions have a good entropy and the corresponding random variable distribution is statistically uniform. If it's not, then let's pretend, that it is.

Then, I have a structure:

```
struct CustomType {
  int field1;
  short field2;
  string field3;
  // ...
};
```

I want to hash it, using separate hashes of some of it's fields, say, `std::hash(field1)` and `std::hash(field2)`. Both hashes are in a set of possible values of the type `size_t`.

What is a good hash-function, that can combine both those results and map them back to `size_t`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`boost::hash_combine` is really good one to hash different fields.

If you don't have boost library you can use this :

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & s, const T & v)
{
  std::hash<T> h;
  s^= h(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (s<< 6) + (s>> 2);
}

 struct S {
  int field1;
  short field2;
  std::string field3;
  // ...
};

template <class T>
class MyHash;

template<>
struct MyHash<S>
{
    std::size_t operator()(S const& s) const 
    {
        std::size_t res = 0;
       hash_combine(res,s.field1);
       hash_combine(res,s.field2);
       hash_combine(res,s.field3);
        return res;
    }
};
```

And then probably  `std::unordered_set<S> s;` , etc

Comment: Read [Magic number in boost::hash_combine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948780/1870232)

Answer (score 10):

`boost::hash_combine` is something that could help you out here:

```
namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<CustomType>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const CustomType& c) const
    {
        std::size_t result = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(result, field1);
        boost::hash_combine(result, field2);
        return result;
    }
};
}
```

See the boost doc [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach may be to add a toString() method and hash that.

```
struct CustomType {
    int field1;
    short field2;
    std::string field3;
    // ...

    std::string toString() const {
        return std::to_string(field1) + std::to_string(field2) + field3; // + ...
    }

    size_t hash() const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(toString());
    }

};
```

Having the toString() method is also handy for logging and debugging.