# Make nested type hash-able for std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, hash, unordered-set

I have a template structs. struct foo has nested type.

```
template<typename Data>
struct Bar{
};

template<typename Data>
struct Foo {
typedef typename std::pair<Bar<Data>*,Foo<Data>*> Pointers;
std::unordered_set<Pointers> pointers;
};
```

I want make Pointers hashable that will fit to `std::unordered_set<Pointers>`

I read here:

[How to specialize std::hash::operator() for user-defined type in unordered containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered)

[How to properly hash the custom struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195183/how-to-properly-hash-the-custom-struct)

[boost::hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html)

[Templates and nested classes/structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694063/templates-and-nested-classes-structures)

And combine all the knowledge to this code:

```
namespace std {

  template <typename Dara> struct hash< typename Foo<Data>::Pointers>
  {

    size_t operator()(const typename Foo<Data>::Pointers & x) const
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, x.first);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, x.second);
        return seed;
    }
  };
}
```

At the last piece of code the compiler is throw an error:
 error: template parameters not used in partial specialization:
 `Data` at the point to here:  typename Data.

I try to delete the data from template and use it like this:
`template <> struct hash< typename Foo::Pointers>`
but the the compiler tell me that it wrong type for template.

How i correct my code?

Regards,
Tal.

Comment: The Pointers type is not hash-able. it not compile, and assert of `std::hash` as fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simpler Solution:
Add boost::hash:

make Foo struct to be like that:

```
template<typename Data>
struct Foo {
typedef typename std::pair<Bar<Data>*,Foo<Data>*> Pointers;
std::unordered_set<Pointers,boost::hash<Pointers> pointers;
};
```

Read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160889/how-to-make-unordered-set-of-pairs-of-integers-in-c):

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specialize on nested types. The compiler can't deduce what you are trying to specialize. You can specialize `std::hash<...>` for the appropriate type directly, though:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename Data>
    struct hash<std::pair<Bar<Data>*,Foo<Data>*>> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that pointers generally don't make good keys. You may want to use `*x.first` and `*x.second` with `hash_combine()`.

Comment: Thanks! but i found simple solution! :)
I will post it, when I allow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice with the pointer. I guess using boost::hash with it, it will be better.