# Make simple tuple conform to Hashable, so can be a Dictionary Key

Tags: swift, dictionary, protocols, hashable

I'd like to use a very simple tuple as a key:

```
(Int, Int)
```

Dictionary keys need to be Hashable. I've learnt.

But can't find how I make this simple tuple Hashable, and do struggle with protocol conformance at the best of times.

More profoundly, a CGPoint would solve my problems. It can be of this format, but is not hashable.

Is it possible to extend a CGPoint so it's hashable? If so, how?

EDIT: Image of Int variant of CGPoint choice.

[image]

Comment: Related: [In Swift can I use a tuple as the key in a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24131323/2976878)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making conform to `Hashable` is not difficult for class, struct or enum.
You just need to explicitly declare conformance to `Hashable` and define a property `hashValue: Int`. Practically, the `hashValue` needs to fulfill one simple axiom: ***if a == b then a.hashValue == b.hashValue***.

(To conform `Hashable`, you also need to make the type `Equatable`. In case of `CGPoint`, it is already `Equatable`.)

An example to make `CGPoint` conform to `Hashable`:

```
extension CGPoint: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        //This expression can be any of the arbitrary expression which fulfills the axiom above.
        return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue
    }
}

var pointDict: [CGPoint: String] = [
    CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2.0): "PointA",
    CGPoint(x: 3.0, y: 4.0): "PointB",
    CGPoint(x: 5.0, y: 6.0): "PointC",
]
print(pointDict[CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2.0)]) //->Optional("PointA")
```

As `CGPoint` contains `CGFloat` values, so, `CGPoint` as Key of Dictionary may cause unexpected behavior based on the calculation error of binary floating-point system. You need to use it with extra caution.

---

**ADDITION**

If you want to avoid some calculation error issue and can accept that the structure can only contain `Int`s, you can define your own struct and make it conform to `Hashable`:

```
struct MyPoint {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}
extension MyPoint: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue
    }

    public static func == (lhs: MyPoint, rhs: MyPoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
    }
}
var myPointDict: [MyPoint: String] = [
    MyPoint(x: 1, y: 2): "MyPointA",
    MyPoint(x: 3, y: 4): "MyPointB",
    MyPoint(x: 5, y: 6): "MyPointC",
]
print(myPointDict[MyPoint(x: 1, y: 2)]) //->Optional("MyPointA")
```

Not much more difficult than the code above, one more thing you need is just defining `==` operator for the struct. Please make it a try.

Comment: Excellent. About the floats, can I force use of the CGPoint variant that is based on Integers?

Comment: Added image to question as I can't add to a comment here

Comment: Even if you use the initializer of `CGPoint` taking `Int`, the values are internally converted to `CGFloat`. If you mean your own struct with _the CGPoint variant_, you can do it. You can write something like `struct MyPoint: Hashable {...}`, just that you need to define both `hashValue` property and `==` operator.

Comment: Good to know about the use of CGFloats internally. Thank you!! Creating my own struct is too confusing, for me... I'm...

Comment: Added some example code for defining your own struct. Not too difficult, I think. Just practice.

Comment: OH! Now I'm all giddy with power. I can shape the world. Of code ;). One question, and I apologise for my profuse lack of OOP grokkery. Why is this a class static func rather than a struct that works like: `let myStruct = MyPoint(x: 2, y: 3)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I cannot get what you mean with the last question. You are asking about the definition of `==`? Or something about initializer? Or just class or struct issue?

Comment: Sorry. Let me try again. You have chosen to use a class static function, so the hashable "value" is `MyPoint[x: 1, y: 2]` since the class name is now part of that which is hashable. Is this because it's not possible to create struct instances that are hashable? Or some other reason? To be honest, this entire part confuses me deeply: `public static func == (lhs: MyPoint, rhs: MyPoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y`

Comment: Defining an operator with `public static` (`MyPoint` is not a class, so it should be called as "type static", not "class static"), is a requirement when writing an operator to conform to some protocol declaring the operator. The type of the arguments of the operator is `MyPoint`, so with that definition you can write something like this: `let p1 = MyPoint(x: 1, y: 2)` `let p2 = MyPoint(x: 1, y: 2)` `if p1 == p2 {...}`. When you compare two `MyPoint`s, you may want to compare both `x` and `y`, no?

Comment: Maybe. I think this comes back to my problems of understanding how the conformance is achieved through this comparison. To my mind (designer viewpoint), that this is not somehow more automatic is a function of poor design of the language... but I have no height from which to make that claim. It just seems like a complete mess of boilerplate, arbitrariness and contrivance. And pisses me off. Sorry.

Comment: And, I'm absolutely infuriated that Ints, both of which are hashable, can't be used in a tuple as a key for a dictionary. That looks like it's deliberately designed to annoy, or a half arsed tuple implementation in the language. But... again, I am coming at this from a very naive point of view. And heading towards trying to learn NSCoding, which my previewing of makes me even more infuriated by the absolute lack of care in design and communication of what and how, where and when, and why.

Comment: Maybe your complaints about the current status of Swift is reasonable. Just that I (or many other users writing answers to Swift questions) are too accustomed to the current Swift. To improve Swift, some fresh point of view must be needed. Participating in a ML of swift.org, or writing a feature request with [Apple's bug reporter](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) would be a good starting point.

Comment: My reactions are at a gut, instinctual and (sometimes) aesthetic and interpretive level. They're not borne out of reason or understanding of compilers and programming language paradigms of old, but a vision and dream of how they could be. No doubt a good dose of ignorance and naivety contributes to my views, too.

Comment: In older Swift, you cannot even [compare tuples](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md). Someone raised a simple, primitive opinion where Swift developers can see, and the opinion was refined to the proposal, and now it's a part of Swift. I would not say any more about this, but sharing sort of complaints is not always a bad thing.

Comment: Is this the part that conforms CGPoint to hashable: `return x.hashValue ^ y.hashValue`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your `this` is addressing. I just have expressed that Swift is changing. In older Swift, this sort of comparison was invalid -- `if (x,y) == (1,2) {...}`, now you can do it in Swift 3. There may be some chance on making tuples or structs automatically `Hashable`, or at least on knowing why Swift Team would not do it.