# Why is the magic number in boost::hash_combine specified in hex

Tags: c++, boost, hash

The magic number in this case is 0x9e3779b9, which in base 10 is 2654435769. Is there any reason why the code

```
seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
```

uses the hex representation instead of the base-10 representation? Would the functionality remain identical if 2654435769 was substituted for 0x9e3779b9 in the code?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-number-in-boosthash-combine

Comment: As an aside, the value of the constant uses the golden ratio: 2654435769 = 2^32*(2/(1 + sqrt(5)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Literals are literals and different representations of the same literal are... literally identical.

However, expressions (literal or not) also have a ***type***.

The equivalent literal would have been `2654435769u` (note the type suffix making it `unsigned`).

Look at this simple test  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee003d804d12acae)**

- `0x9e3779b9` has type `unsigned int` (32 bit) and
- `2654435769` has type `long` (64 bit)
- `2654435769u` has type `unsigned int` (32 bit) again

As you can see, the hex representation favours unsigned and the decimal representation favours signed, making the type bigger¹.

---

¹ native integer sizes are implementation defined

(Beyond types, one could argue that maybe, perhaps, bit-distribution is slightly more apparent in hex, octal or ultimately binary representations)