# Swift Hashing algorithm using bit shifting to avoid collisions

Tags: swift, algorithm, hash

Given a `Person` struct that has a `name` and `surname` string properties I would like to write an hashing algorithm that is efficient and avoids collisions for persons with interchangeable names and surnames (Lara Ray and Ray Lara for example.).

I already know to stir away from string concatenation in Swift, so Ideally I am thinking at `XOR`ing the 2 variables and bit shifting one of them to solve the interchangeable problem.
Is there anything wrong with this?

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let surname: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        return surname.hashValue << 1 ^ name.hashValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a good place to start would be a Regex subclass.. Will look into it

Comment: Check out the hash combine function here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/148777/73433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin R graciously provided a Swift translation of Boost's [hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) function in an old Code Review post of mine [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/148777/73433).

We can use this function in your struct:

```
func hash_combine(seed: inout UInt, value: UInt) {
    let tmp = value &+ 0x9e3779b9 &+ (seed << 6) &+ (seed >> 2)
    seed ^= tmp
}

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let surname: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        var seed = UInt(0)
        hash_combine(seed: &seed, value: UInt(bitPattern: name.hashValue))
        hash_combine(seed: &seed, value: UInt(bitPattern: surname.hashValue))
        return Int(bitPattern: seed)
    }
}

Person(name: "Joe", surname: "Smith").hashValue // -5143836311621647467
Person(name: "Smith", surname: "Joe").hashValue // -5146825509308597586
```

While not perfect, this should reduce the number of collisions in a huge sample set (see the linked post of an example with `CGPoint`).

You can read more about the "golden ratio" here: [Magic number in boost::hash_combine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948780/2415822)

I'm still testing this, but I imagine this would provide fewer collisions than just bit shifting by 1.