# Generic hash for tuples in unordered_map / unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, unordered-map, unordered-set

Why doesn't `std::unordered_map<tuple<int, int>, string>` just 
work out of the box? 
It is tedious to have to define a hash function for `tuple<int, int>`, e.g.

```
template<> struct do_hash<tuple<int, int>>                               
{   size_t operator()(std::tuple<int, int> const& tt) const {...}  };
```

[Building an unordered map with tuples as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611951/building-an-unordered-map-with-tuples-as-keys) (Matthieu M.) shows how to
automate this for `boost::tuple`. Is there anyway of doing this for c++0x tuples without using variadic templates?

Surely this should be in the standard :(

Comment: If you're using C++0x why not use variadic templates? (or is there an implementation with tuples, but no varidic templates?)

Comment: @RMartinho : VC++ 2010 matches that description (and it seems the next version of VC++ is likely to as well).

Comment: If std::tuple is implemented by manually writing out templates of 1 to N-arity (like boost::tuple), then I guess the std::hash specialisation necessary to hash the tuples will also have to be manually written out (using too clever preprocessing?) the same way. Aaargh!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This works on gcc 4.5 allowing all c++0x tuples containing standard hashable types to be members of
`unordered_map` and `unordered_set` without further ado.
(I put the code in a header file and just include it.)

The function has to live in the std namespace so that it is picked up by
argument-dependent name lookup (ADL).

Is there a simpler solution?

```
#include <tuple>
namespace std{
    namespace
    {

        // Code from boost
        // Reciprocal of the golden ratio helps spread entropy
        //     and handles duplicates.
        // See Mike Seymour in magic-numbers-in-boosthash-combine:
        //     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780

        template <class T>
        inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
        {
            seed ^= std::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }

        // Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
        template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
        struct HashValueImpl
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
            hash_combine(seed, std::get<Index>(tuple));
          }
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            hash_combine(seed, std::get<0>(tuple));
          }
        };
    }

    template <typename ... TT>
    struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
    {
        size_t
        operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const
        {                                              
            size_t seed = 0;                             
            HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
            return seed;                                 
        }                                              

    };
}
```

### Standard Conformant code

Yakk points out that specialising things in the std namespace is actually undefined behaviour. If you wish to have a standards conforming solution, then you need to move all of this code into your own namespace and give up any idea of ADL finding the right hash implementation automatically. Instead of :

```
unordered_set<tuple<double, int> > test_set;
```

You need:

```
unordered_set<tuple<double, int>, hash_tuple::hash<tuple<double, int>>> test2;
```

where `hash_tuple` is your own namespace rather than `std::`.

To do this, you first have to declare a hash implementation inside the `hash_tuple` namespace. This will forward all non tuple types to the `std::hash`:

```
namespace hash_tuple{

template <typename TT>
struct hash
{
    size_t
    operator()(TT const& tt) const
    {                                              
        return std::hash<TT>()(tt);                                 
    }                                              
};
}
```

Make sure that `hash_combine` calls `hash_tuple::hash` and not `std::hash`

```
namespace hash_tuple{

namespace
    {
    template <class T>
    inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
    {
        seed ^= hash_tuple::hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
    }
}
```

Then include all the other previous code but put it inside `namespace hash_tuple` and not `std::`

```
namespace hash_tuple{

    namespace
    {
        // Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
        template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
        struct HashValueImpl
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
            hash_combine(seed, std::get<Index>(tuple));
          }
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            hash_combine(seed, std::get<0>(tuple));
          }
        };
    }

    template <typename ... TT>
    struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
    {
        size_t
        operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const
        {                                              
            size_t seed = 0;                             
            HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
            return seed;                                 
        }                                              
    };

}
```

Comment: Assuming you don't want to use boost libraries shouldn't you have std::hash_combine instead of boost::hash_combine?

Comment: Is there a std::hash_combine?

Comment: Your template compiled using std::hash_combine with gcc 4.6.3. I made the switch to avoid using boost

Comment: @LeoGoodstadt: +1. Your hash is almost certainly better than bare XOR. I've been told that `seed += hash(v); seed *= m`, where *m* is a large odd number, is a good choice, but I don't know whether its better or worse than yours.

Comment: @Bo Lu: I was wondering what you were talking about since I include the hash_combine explicitly to avoid boost dependencies. Then I noticed I forgot to remove the boost namespace qualifier from my code... Hope it still works.

Comment: Not worth the undefined behavior: don't specialize things in `std::` involving things you do not own, and you don't own `std::tuple<TT...>`.  As a concrete exmaple of how this could horribly break code, what happens when a new iteration of the standard introduces its own hash specialization?  What happens when someone else who has your bright idea introduces a narrow `hash<tuple<int>>` specialization, which is visible from some but not all places where `hash<tuple<int>>` is used?  Those are concrete examples, but the UB is not bounded by them.  Your program is ill formed.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk. Answer updated to suggest avoiding the `std::` namespace.

Comment: Doesn't touching std result in undefined behavior? Does using an anon namespace in std get around that??

Comment: @allyourcode This is old, but adding specializations to the std namespace is actually recommended. Adding classes, functions, or other definitions is explicitly forbidden.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh You can add specializations into `std` namespace only for custom types (therefore not for `std::tuple`). This is what Yakk mentioned in his/her comment.

Comment: @DanielLangr Neither mine nor @Yakk's comments are contradictory. You are expressly encouraged to add specializations in the `std` namespace, doing so for types already in the standard library is bound to cause problems.

Comment: rather than having `hash_tuple::hash` be a template, you could have a single `hash_tuple` object with a template `operator()`

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <tuple>

namespace std
{

template<typename... T>
struct hash<tuple<T...>>
{
    size_t operator()(tuple<T...> const& arg) const noexcept
    {
        return boost::hash_value(arg);
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 12):

With C++20, it is possible to use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and [generic lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to compute hash of a tuple without recursion. I prefer to rely on `std::hash<uintmax_t>` instead of manually combining hashes:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

class hash_tuple {
    template<class T>
    struct component {
        const T& value;
        component(const T& value) : value(value) {}
        uintmax_t operator,(uintmax_t n) const {
            n ^= std::hash<T>()(value);
            n ^= n << (sizeof(uintmax_t) * 4 - 1);
            return n ^ std::hash<uintmax_t>()(n);
        }
    };

public:
    template<class Tuple>
    size_t operator()(const Tuple& tuple) const {
        return std::hash<uintmax_t>()(
            std::apply([](const auto& ... xs) { return (component(xs), ..., 0); }, tuple));
    }
};
```

`- 1` in `sizeof(uintmax_t) * 4 - 1` is optional, but appears to slightly improve hash distribution. This class can be used both with `std::tuple` and `std::pair`.

Comment: n ^= n << (sizeof(uintmax_t) * 4 - 1);

Comment: Note that the line "n ^ std::hash<uintmax_t>()(n);" will only return 0 on platforms where the default hash function is identity, making this hash function useless.

Comment: Usage of ```operator,``` vs. ```operator+``` or ```operator^```, the latter two seem more appropriate of course subjectively speaking.

Answer (score 10):

In my C++0x draft, `20.8.15` says hash is specialized for built-in types (including pointers, but doesn't seem to imply dereferencing them).  It also appears to be specialized for `error_code`, `bitset<N>`, `unique_ptr<T, D>`, `shared_ptr<T>`, `typeindex`, `string`, `u16string`, `u32string`, `wstring`, `vector<bool, Allocator>`, and `thread::id`.  (facinating list!)

I've not used C++0x variadics, so my formatting is probably way off, but something along these lines might work for all tuples.

```
size_t hash_combiner(size_t left, size_t right) //replacable
{ return left + 0x9e3779b9 + (right<<6) + (right>>2);}

template<int index, class...types>
struct hash_impl {
    size_t operator()(size_t a, const std::tuple<types...>& t) const {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<types...>>::type nexttype;
        hash_impl<index-1, types...> next;
        size_t b = std::hash<nexttype>()(std::get<index>(t));
        return next(hash_combiner(a, b), t); 
    }
};
template<class...types>
struct hash_impl<0, types...> {
    size_t operator()(size_t a, const std::tuple<types...>& t) const {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<types...>>::type nexttype;
        size_t b = std::hash<nexttype>()(std::get<0>(t));
        return hash_combiner(a, b); 
    }
};

template<class...types>
struct tuple_hash<std::tuple<types...>> {
    size_t operator()(const std::tuple<types...>& t) {
        const size_t begin = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<types...>>::value-1;
        return hash_impl<begin, types...>()(0, t);
    }
}
```

[This version actually compiles and runs](http://ideone.com/fkFWl)

Yakk has observed that specializing `std::hash` directly is *technically* not allowed, since we're specializing a standard library template with a declaration that does *not* depend on a user-defined type.

Comment: Use `left() ^ right()` if you don't know what to do. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes . But note that XOR is not always the right choice. Using plain addition can turn out to be better if you expect the tuples to contain duplicate members. This is probably the reason why there is no standard hash for tuples.

Comment: It must be an oversight that tuple is not hashable. Too late for the standard though :(

Comment: @Leo oddly enough, no container except for vector<bool>, and basic_string is hashable. (is bitset technically a container?)

Comment: oh, I just now noticed: `without using variadic templates?` whoops.  The answer is no, can't be done for all tuples, since a tuple is a variadic template type.

Comment: @Alexandre Turns out this revised code looks almost exactly like my answer (after reformatting for whitespace) except that (1) I use a different (more robust?) way of dealing with entropy when combining hash values and (2) I don't have to deduce the type of the "next" tuple value explicitly using std::tuple_element because my hash_combine function is parameterised on its type.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: `^` and `+` are both commutative, and are thus poor choices for combining hashes. Consider how `std::unordered_set<std::tuple<int, int, …>>` would handle permutations of {1, 2, …, 10}. Instead, use a non-commutative combiner such as `m * left + right`, where *m* is a large odd number.

Comment: Specializing `hash` for a type you do not own means your program is ill formed.  And you don't own all of `hash<tuple<Ts...>>`.  And `^` is a horrible hash combiner.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in a simple way. Just do

```
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<int, int>, std::string, boost::hash<std::tuple<int, int>>> mp;
```