# Unordered Map with three unsigned chars as key

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable, unordered-map, hash-function

I have to make an unordered_map consisting of the following keys and value:

- key: unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char
- value: structure(int,int)

Here is my code to define that:

```
namespace G {

typedef std::tuple< unsigned char, unsigned char , unsigned char> key_t;


struct IndexGuide
{
int index;
int SerialNo;

};

typedef std::unordered_map<const key_t,IndexGuide> GuideDouble;

}
using namespace G;
```

Is there anything wrong in this code because when I link these files on linux terminal. It gives me errors.Some part of the error as follows

> In function `std::__detail::_Hash_code_base const, std::pair const, G::IndexGuide>,
>   std::_Select1st const, G::IndexGuide> >,
>   std::equal_to
>   const>, std::hash const>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
>   false>::_M_bucket_index(std::__detail::_Hash_node const, G::IndexGuide>, false>
>   const*, unsigned int) const':

Comment: you have to provide a hash function which tells unordered_map how to produce a hash value from your key_t

Comment: Please share the full error with us. The part that you posted only says that there is an error, but not which one.

Comment: Remove the `const` from the `const key_t` in the `typedef`; it's not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your basic problem is that you don't have a hasher for `std::tuple` -- the standard library does not currently come with one by default.  I think this is an oversight.

You cannot add a default hasher for `std::tuple` -- either for all `tuple`s or for your particular list -- because the standard says you aren't allowed to:

> **17.6.4.2.1** Namespace std [namespace.std]/1 The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to
>   namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise
>   specified. A program may add a template specialization for any
>   standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration
>   depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the
>   standard library requirements for the original template and is not
>   explicitly prohibited.

So this leaves you with either writing a custom hasher for your `tuple` type, and passing it to your `unordered_map`, or using a type that isn't merely `std::tuple` for your key, or writing a custom hasher that supports every `tuple` (including recursive `tuple`s) while also supporting `hash<T>` lookup for non-`tuple`s.  A 4th option would be to write your own ADL-based hash system and set it up so that types with valid `std::hash` specializations use that, with various other fallbacks.

I will illustrate the 3rd option above.

First, you want to be able to combine two hash values in a way that doesn't lead to many spurious collisions.

```
  inline std::size_t hash_result_combine(std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs)
  {
      return lhs ^( rhs + 0x9e3779b9 + (lhs<<6) + (lhs>>2));
  }
```

this takes two `hash` outputs, and combines them.  We can then chain this any number of times.  (constants borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111460/1774667 )

Next, some indexing boilerplate.  Most generic work with `std::tuple` requires this stuff:

```
  template<unsigned...>struct indexes{};
  template<unsigned Max, unsigned... Is>struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1,Max-1,Is...> {};
  template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
```

Finally, a hasher class that works with nearly every type:

```
  struct my_hasher {
    template<typename... Args>
    std::size_t operator()(indexes<>, std::tuple<Args...> const& tup) const {
      return 0;
    }
    template<unsigned I, unsigned... Is,typename... Args>
    std::size_t operator()(indexes<I, Is...>,std::tuple<Args...> const& tup) const {
      return hash_result_combine( (*this)(std::get<I>(tup)), (*this)(indexes<Is...>, tup) );
    }
    template<typename... Args>
    std::size_t operator()(std::tuple<Args...> const& tup) const {
      return (*this)(make_indexes<sizeof...(Args)>(), tup);
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const& t) const { return std::hash<T>()(t); }
  };
```

you can pass `my_hasher` to an `unordered_set` in place of `hash<T>` for `tuple`s, `tuple`s containing tuples, or even for scalars -- it is very generous.

```
typedef std::unordered_map<const key_t,IndexGuide, my_hasher> GuideDouble;
```

and now we properly hash `key_t`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a hash function which tells `std::unordered_map` how to produce a hash value from your `key_t`. You can do it by specialization of `hash` template functor:

provide a Key:

```
struct Key{
    unsigned char  first;
    unsigned char second;
    unsigned char  third;

    bool operator==(const Key &other) const {
         return (first == other.first
            && second == other.second
            && third == other.third);
    }
};
```

specialize hash template:

```
namespace std {

  template <>
  struct hash< Key>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
      using std::hash;

      // Compute individual hash values for first,
      // second and third and combine them using XOR
      // and bit shifting:

      return ((hash<char>()( k.first)
               ^ (hash<char>()( k.second) << 1)) >> 1)
               ^ (hash<int>()( k.third) << 1);
    }
  };

}

std::unordered_map< Key, IndexGuide> myMap;
```

As I said in comments, you can take a look [at this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/1141471).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `struct hash<key_t>` instead of `struct hash<Key>`?

Comment: yes, of course, fixed

Comment: I personally would think that avoiding undefined behavior is an asset.  You may not specialize types in `std` when the specialization does not involve any user-owned types.  `key_t` is a `std::tuple` (a `template` from `std`) and the arguments to the `template` are all basic types.  Rather, you should write your own hasher, and pass it manually to the `unordered_map`.  And while this is somewhat academic, I could easily see the above breaking horribly if they added `hash` specializations to `tuple`.

Comment: Your hash combination is only mediocre as well (not horrible, just mediocre) -- I'd duplicate `boost`s technique myself.

Comment: this is not undefined behavior to specialize hash template this way. According to the body of hash function: this is just merely example, you are free to do whatever you want in there. I agree it would be better to create class Key and specialized template on it

Comment: @piotruś That is only because you changed the answer after I made a comment.

Comment: no, you have to refer to the changed version because you didn't respond on time. Yes, I was talking about version with tuple, if you think this was UB please show appropriate quote from the standard

Comment: **17.6.4.2.1 Namespace std**
[namespace.std]/ 1 ""The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.""

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_set` is implemented using a hash table.
in order to use `unordered_set` for a type that you defined you need to specialize the `hash<>` template for that type,  as follows:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<key_t>
    {

        size_t operator()(const key_t & t) const
        {
            // the logic for hashing
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: this would invoke Undefined Behavior, class key_t must be a user class

Answer (score 0):

There is no default hasher for std::tuple.

You may use this code snippet [Generic hash for tuples in unordered_map / unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7115547/1961500)