# Why did the C++ standards committee not include std::hash for pair and tuple?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, standards

As pointed out in answers to [Generic hash for tuples in unordered_map / unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110301/) and elsewhere, [Boost has an implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#id-1_3_11_11_2_2_27_1_35-bb) of `boost::hash<tuple<string, string>>`.

So, we can do things like:

```cpp
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

std::tuple<string, string> t;
size_t bh = boost::hash<tuple<string, string>>{}(t);
boost::unordered_map<tuple<string, string>, int> bm;
```

but not:

```cpp
size_t sh = std::hash<tuple<string, string>>{}(t); // error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.
std::unordered_map<tuple<string, string>, int> sm; // same error
```

**Why didn't this make it into the C++ standard?**

Extra points for references with a rationale given by the committee or other experts.

Comment: Because they couldn't agree on the right way to do it. Still debating it these days...

Comment: The obvious choice for a tuple is to hash each element and combine the hashes.  Mathematically combining hashes is still an interesting topic.

Comment: Some additional reflections in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x/2595226#2595226).

Comment: A good **nine** papers attempting to standardize this can be seen [here](http://bajamircea.github.io/coding/cpp/2017/06/09/unordered-hash.html#references)

Comment: Thanks, Drew Dormann. That [Unordered hash conumdrum](https://bajamircea.github.io/coding/cpp/2017/06/09/unordered-hash.html) article explains it well and has further references. So it could count as the accepted answer.

Comment: @nielses if DrewDromann doesn't write an answer you should write one yourself. It's encouraged to answer your own question as long as you write a good answer. In this case provide the links, summarize them and quote the most relevant parts.

Comment: If OP is 400k+ in rep I usually assume they know how the site works :)