# How to declare/use an `unordered_set` for triplets (`tuple`) using custom comparator?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

How to declare/use an `unordered_set` for triplets (`tuple`) using custom comparator?

I need to store triplets of `float` (handled as `tuple`) in a set to check for potential duplicates. As it's about `float`, I guess using regular compare with `==` will not work so customizing compare is needed.

This minimal code doesn't compile:

```
>> cat unordered_set_triplet.cpp 
#include <unordered_set>
#include <tuple>
#include <limits> // numeric_limits
#include <cmath> // fabs
#include <functional> // hash

using triplet = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
bool triplet_equal(triplet const & lhs, triplet const & rhs) {
  float const eps = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
  if (std::fabs(std::get<0>(lhs) - std::get<0>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  if (std::fabs(std::get<1>(lhs) - std::get<1>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  if (std::fabs(std::get<2>(lhs) - std::get<2>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  return true;
}
using unordered_set_triplet = std::unordered_set<triplet,
                                                 std::hash<triplet>,
                                                 decltype(triplet_equal)>;

int main() {
  //unordered_set_triplet s; // Compilation: KO...
  unordered_set_triplet s(10, std::hash<triplet>, triplet_equal);
  s.insert({1.f, 2.f, 3.f});
}
```

I get:

```
>> g++ -std=c++20 -o unordered_set_triplet unordered_set_triplet.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/unordered_set:46,
                 from unordered_set_triplet.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<0, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&), false>’:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1631:12:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_base<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::__detail::_Identity, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&), std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable.h:182:11:   required from ‘class std::_Hashtable<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::allocator<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, std::__detail::_Identity, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&), std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >’
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unordered_set.h:100:18:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&)>’
unordered_set_triplet.cpp:21:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1204:11: error: data member ‘std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper<0, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&), false>::_M_tp’ invalidly declared function type
 1204 |       _Tp _M_tp{};
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::_Hashtable<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::allocator<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, std::__detail::_Identity, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&), std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >’:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unordered_set.h:100:18:   required from ‘class std::unordered_set<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&)>’
unordered_set_triplet.cpp:21:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/hashtable.h:665:7: error: function returning a function
  665 |       key_eq() const
      |       ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/unordered_set:47:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unordered_set.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::unordered_set<std::tuple<float, float, float>, std::hash<std::tuple<float, float, float> >, bool(const std::tuple<float, float, float>&, const std::tuple<float, float, float>&)>’:
unordered_set_triplet.cpp:21:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/unordered_set.h:632:7: error: function returning a function
  632 |       key_eq() const
      |       ^~~~~~
unordered_set_triplet.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
unordered_set_triplet.cpp:21:49: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   21 |   unordered_set_triplet s(10, std::hash<triplet>, triplet_equal);
      |                                                 ^
```

How to fix this?

**EDIT**

Doesn't work either using (ordered) `set`:

```
>> cat set_triplet.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <limits> // numeric_limits
#include <cmath> // fabs
#include <functional> // hash

using triplet = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
bool triplet_equal(triplet const & lhs, triplet const & rhs) {
  float const eps = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
  if (std::fabs(std::get<0>(lhs) - std::get<0>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  if (std::fabs(std::get<1>(lhs) - std::get<1>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  if (std::fabs(std::get<2>(lhs) - std::get<2>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
  return true;
}
using set_triplet = std::set<triplet, std::hash<triplet>, decltype(triplet_equal)>;

int main() {
  //set_triplet s; // Compilation: KO...
  set_triplet s(10, std::hash<triplet>, triplet_equal);
  s.insert({1.f, 2.f, 3.f});
  s.insert({1.0000001f, 2.0000001f, 3.0000001f});
  for (auto const & t : s) std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", " << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl;
}
```

What container could be appropriate to use?
`triplet` can be seen a 3D point (XYZ): I need to handle/detect duplicate points.

**SOLUTION: USING SET (NOT UNORDERED SET) AND INT (NOT FLOAT) WITHOUT IMPLEMENTING LESS**

Using tuples made of integer `i` built this way `i = (int) 1000000 * f`  from float `f` and using set (as `operator<` will respect strict ordering up to 6-digit precision after multiplication by 1000000).

```
>> cat set_uint32_triplet.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

using triplet_uint32 = std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>;
using triplet_float = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
triplet_uint32 convert(triplet_float const & f) {
  uint32_t precision = 1000000; // Allow for 6-digit precision.
  uint32_t x = (uint32_t) (std::get<0>(f) * precision);
  uint32_t y = (uint32_t) (std::get<1>(f) * precision);
  uint32_t z = (uint32_t) (std::get<2>(f) * precision);
  return {x, y, z};
}

int main() {
  triplet_float pt1 = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f};
  triplet_float pt2 = {1.0000001f, 2.0000001f, 3.0000001f}; // Considered     duplicate with pt1.
  triplet_float pt3 = {1.000001f,  2.000001f,  3.000001f};  // Considered NOT duplicate with pt1.

  std::set<triplet_uint32> s;
  s.insert(convert(pt1));
  s.insert(convert(pt2));
  s.insert(convert(pt3));
  std::cout << "set size " << s.size() << std::endl;
  for (auto const & t : s) std::cout << "set item " << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", " << std::get<2>(t) << ", " << std::endl;
}

>> g++ -std=c++20 -o set_uint32_triplet set_uint32_triplet.cpp

>> ./set_uint32_triplet 
set size 2
set item 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 
set item 1000000, 2000001, 3000001,
```

**SOLUTION: USING SET (NOT UNORDERED SET) AND INT (NOT FLOAT) WITH IMPLEMENTING LESS**

```
>> cat set_uint32_triplet_less.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

#define FLOAT_TO_INT(x) ((x)>=0?(int32_t)((x)+0.5):(int32_t)((x)-0.5))

using triplet_int32 = std::tuple<int32_t, int32_t, int32_t>;
using triplet_float = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
triplet_int32 convert(triplet_float const & f) {
  int32_t precision = 1000; // Allow for 3-digit precision.
  int32_t x = FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<0>(f) * precision);
  int32_t y = FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<1>(f) * precision);
  int32_t z = FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<2>(f) * precision);
  //std::cout.precision(10);
  //std::cout << "convert: " << std::get<0>(f) << ", " << std::get<1>(f) << ", " << std::get<2>(f);
  //std::cout << " - " << std::get<0>(f) * precision << ", " << std::get<1>(f) * precision << ", " << std::get<2>(f) * precision;
  //std::cout << " - " << FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<0>(f) * precision) << ", " << FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<1>(f) * precision) << ", " << FLOAT_TO_INT(std::get<2>(f) * precision);
  //std::cout << " - " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << std::endl;
  return {x, y, z};
}
struct less {
  bool operator()(triplet_int32 const & lhs,
                  triplet_int32 const & rhs) const {
    bool res = true; // lhs < rhs.
    if      (std::get<0>(lhs) >= std::get<0>(rhs)) res = false;
    else if (std::get<1>(lhs) >= std::get<1>(rhs)) res = false;
    else if (std::get<2>(lhs) >= std::get<2>(rhs)) res = false;
    //std::cout << "  less: " << std::get<0>(lhs) << ", " << std::get<1>(lhs) << ", " << std::get<2>(lhs);
    //std::cout <<    " - " << std::get<0>(rhs) << ", " << std::get<1>(rhs) << ", " << std::get<2>(rhs);
    //std::cout << " - res " << res << std::endl;
    return res; // lhs < rhs.
  }
};

int main() {
  triplet_float pt1 = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f};
  triplet_float pt2 = {1.0001f, 2.0001f, 3.0001f}; // Considered     duplicate with pt1.
  triplet_float pt3 = {1.001f,  2.001f,  3.001f};  // Considered NOT duplicate with pt1.

  std::set<triplet_int32, less> s;
  s.insert(convert(pt1));
  s.insert(convert(pt2));
  s.insert(convert(pt3));
  std::cout << "set size " << s.size() << std::endl;
  for (auto const & t : s) std::cout << "set item " << std::get<0>(t) << ", " << std::get<1>(t) << ", " << std::get<2>(t) << ", " << std::endl;
}
>> g++ -std=c++20 -o set_uint32_triplet_less set_uint32_triplet_less.cpp
>> ./set_uint32_triplet_less 
set size 2
set item 1000, 2000, 3000, 
set item 1001, 2001, 3001,
```

Comment: IMO, such a comparator cannot work with unordered containers. The requirement is that _"If two keys are equivalent, the hash function must return the same value for both keys."_ This will generally not hold for different numbers being closer than epsilon. Link: http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#general-5.sentence-2.

Comment: @DanielLangr: you mean it should work with `set`?

Comment: I don't know what's your application, so I cannot know which container is suitable for you. I just say that you can't use such a closeness-based equality comparator for unordered containers.

Comment: @DanielLangr You can't use them for ordered containers either.

Comment: `std::hash<triplet>` is a type. You can't pass it as a constructor argument. (The compiler says "expected primary-expression" because it's not an expression.)

Comment: I don't think `std::hash` is specialized for tuples.

Comment: Presumably should be `unordered_set_triplet s(10, std::hash<triplet>(), triplet_equal);`. You have compilation errors which are easily fixed, but the whole effort is misconceived because any 'close enough' definition of equality breaks the assumptions on which the standard containers are based.

Comment: Also note: `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` is not a universal value for fuzzy comparison

Comment: Do you need to use floats at all? Can you instead use integers or fixed point arithmetic?

Comment: @Caleth: `Can you instead use integers or fixed point arithmetic?` Instead of using float `f`, I thought of using integer `i` built this way `i = (int) 1000000 * f ` with `1000000` for getting 6 digit precision

Comment: @fghoussen "As it's about float, I guess using regular compare with == will not work".  Using `==` will work.  Please expand on why you suggest it will not.

Comment: @fghoussen "I need to store triplets of float (handled as tuple) in a set to check for potential duplicates." --> Use an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).  Please expand on why you need to compare with an _epsilon_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: as stated, triplet can be seen a 3D point (XYZ): I need to handle/detect duplicate points. I use epsilon to handle float precision as for float `a == b` has no meaning (here I just use absolute check but I could have added relative check too - just make it simple here)

Comment: On the best so far solution posted here, using `set` (based on `operator<`), is custom less implementation needed? Or does default implementation of less works with `std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>`?

Comment: @fghoussen "as for float a == b has no meaning" is unclear.  `a == b`, as FP, certainly has meaning.  There is no need for an _epsilon_ in comparing here in an absolute or relative sense.  What requirement are you trying to meet by using one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Problems with *KeyEqual*

Firstly, the *KeyEqual* provided to the `std::unordered_set` can't be a function, and that's what you're trying to do with `decltype(triplet_equal)`. However, it could be a function pointer. Normally, you should use a function object as follows:

```cpp
struct triplet_equal {
    // note: static constexpr only since C++23, otherwise remove those two
    static constexpr bool operator()(triplet const & lhs, triplet const & rhs) const {
        float const eps = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
        if (std::fabs(std::get<0>(lhs) - std::get<0>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
        if (std::fabs(std::get<1>(lhs) - std::get<1>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
        if (std::fabs(std::get<2>(lhs) - std::get<2>(rhs)) > eps) return false;
        return true;
    }
};

// ...
std::unordered_set<triplet, std::hash<triplet>, triplet_equal> s(10);
```

You don't have to provide any value for the hash or for `triplet_equal` to the constructor because they are default-constructible.

#### Problems with *Hash*

The next *huge* issue is that the standard library has no `std::hash` specialization for tuples. Look into [Generic hash for tuples in unordered_map / unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7110301/5740428) if you want to make your own.

However, even if there was one, the problem remains that two equal tuples (where equality is determined by `triplet_equal`) must also have the same hash. You would have to specialize `std::hash` yourself so that two equal tuples always have the same hash, despite floating-point imprecision. You might be able to do it by quantizing `float`s, but I imagine it would be very difficult to do correctly.

#### Alternative: use `std::set` and provide a *Compare*

It would be much easier to use `std::set`, which only requires you to implement a less-than comparison:

```cpp
// checks whether x < y after quantization to a multiple of epsilon
constexpr float eps_less_than(float x, float y) {
    constexpr float e = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
    // use simple comparison if numbers are far apart
    float d = x - y;
    if (std::fabs(d) >= 2 * e) {
        return d < 0;
    }
    return std::floor(x * (1 / e)) < std::floor(y * (1 / e));
}

// lexicographical comparison
struct triplet_less {
    // constexpr since C++23
    constexpr bool operator()(triplet const & lhs, triplet const & rhs) const {
        if (eps_less_than(std::get<0>(lhs), std::get<0>(rhs))) return true;
        if (eps_less_than(std::get<0>(rhs), std::get<0>(lhs))) return false;

        if (eps_less_than(std::get<1>(lhs), std::get<1>(rhs))) return true;
        if (eps_less_than(std::get<1>(rhs), std::get<1>(lhs))) return false;

        if (eps_less_than(std::get<2>(lhs), std::get<2>(rhs))) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<triplet, triplet_less> s;
    s.insert({1.f, 2.f, 3.f});
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/h1oE8h9qr)*

#### Further Notes

It would be much better not to use `std::tuple`, but use a simple aggregate type as follows:

```cpp
struct vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
    // C++20: default all comparison operators
    // (you still need a custom vec3_equal to deal with precision issues)
    friend auto constexpr operator<=>(vec3 const&, vec3 const&) = default;
};
```

With defaulted comparison operators, it's very easy to get all the functionality of `std::tuple`, and you can write `lhs.x` instead of needing `std::get<0>(lhs)` and other annoyances.

Comment: Works !?... Still amazed that something that looked "simple" at first has actually so many implicit traps underneath it!

Comment: alright @BenVoigt, fixed it

Comment: Quantizing `eps_less_than` has very significant limitations which I expect make it useless in practice, but I do think it solves the transitivity issue of `triplet_less`.

Comment: So, instead of `tuple`,  using a dedicated struct `vec3` that implements `operator==` and using `unordered_set` (or `set`) will work?

Comment: @fghoussen: For `unordered_set`, `operator==` is not enough, you also need a hash implementation.  For an ordered `set`, `operator<` is enough, but you have to take care that the relationship it defines is a "strict weak ordering"

Comment: @BenVoigt: thanks for clarifications. So my understanding is that `using tuples made of integer i built this way i = (int) 1000000 * f  from float f` will not even work with `unordered_set` (as `operator==` should be OK but `std::hash` has no specialization for tuples), but, it should work using `set` (as `operator<` will respect strict ordering up to 6-digit precision after multiplication by `1000000`).

Comment: @fghoussen: Yes, quantizing into buckets like that will create a nicely behaved (partial) ordering that `std::set` can use.  And you're just a tuple-hash away from working with `std::unordered_set`, there is none provided in the C++ standard library but plenty of known formula for combining individual field hashes into an overall structure hash.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think your claim that the current approach is "useless in practice" is vastly overstated. The only limitation is that comparisons of numbers past a magnitude of 2^105 might compare positive infinities during quantization.

Comment: @JanSchultke: And because with any numbers with magnitude of `1.0` or higher, this fancy comparison becomes just straight `<` without a tolerance (you noticed and optimized for that after my earlier comment).  And values less than `numeric_limits` epsilon all fall into the same bucket, even if one is a million times the other.  It is probably desirable for the bucket sizes to become larger as the floating-point inputs do.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't understand where that `1.0` is coming from. `1.0` isn't anywhere near the level where my method has numeric issues. See https://godbolt.org/z/qcsPM5c7q

Comment: @JanSchultke: The behavior changes at `1.0` because `1.0` appears in [the definition of epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

Comment: OP wasn't asking for a variable epsilon, so I don't understand why you're making up that requirement right now. I'm also unsure if a variable epsilon would re-introduce transitivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you want, but it offers you a solution to the transitivity issue of the accepted answer.

Use `std::tuple<int, int, int>` and quantize your floats by multiplying them by some constant (say 10000) and rounding them down. The scale factor will depend on your domain.

If you need to keep the original value, use an unordered_map. Use the int tuple for key and add a float tuple for the value.
Then, when you search for a given triplet, you can look up the adjacents tuple in each of the three values.

That is more complex and more work, but it would be a more correct approach and avoid UB due to transitivity issues.